# Copy from browser and paste into local file - Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to test `copy` functionality in selenium. Here in browser contains some grid data, normally I can able to copy that data by using right click and able to paste in local xl sheet. So same functionality trying to test with selenium. 
Now I'm able to do right click on data and can able to click copy by using selenium. After that trying to paste that data into local file is getting exception, namely `java.awt.HeadlessException`.

The below way I've tried to get data and paste:

```
public  String getClipBoardData(){
    try {
        return (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public void writeInFile(String data){
    try{
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("path-to-your-file");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
        out.write(data);
        out.close();
    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I'm not sure, which I am using either correct way or not, If any one have idea please help me out. Here I am getting exception in `getClipBoardData()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getClipboardContents() {
    String result = "";
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    //odd: the Object param of getContents is not currently used
    Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(null);
    boolean hasTransferableText =
      (contents != null) &&
      contents.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    if (hasTransferableText) {
      try {
        result = (String)contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
      }
      catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

try this method in place of  getClipBoardData()

Comment: Yeah tried this already...getting same exception i.e java.awt.HeadlessException

Comment: HeadlessException....

Thrown when code that is dependent on a keyboard, display, or mouse is called in an environment that does not support a keyboard, display, or mouse.

Comment: System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", true); add this as a first line in the above method